# Understanding Function Index

Tags: oracle, index, ddl

Looking at Oracle's docs on the [Function Index](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/indexes.htm#ADMIN11730), what's the meaning of `rivers` in the following?

```
CREATE INDEX area_index ON rivers (area(geo));

SELECT id, geo, area(geo), desc
     FROM rivers     
     WHERE Area(geo) >5000;
```

What's the importance of `rivers` with respect to this query?

Could `dual` have just been used?

Comment: `rivers` is the table name.

Answer (score 3):

It is the name of the table that the index is created on.

This:

```
CREATE INDEX area_index ON rivers (area(geo));
```

.. creates a functional index on the `rivers` table, that uses the function `area()` on the column `geo`.

In simple terms, Oracle creates an index that pre-calculates the value of `area(geo)`, thus making any lookups faster.

The query you have posted:

```
SELECT id, geo, area(geo), desc
FROM rivers     
WHERE Area(geo) >5000;
```

... can use the `area_index` functional index to select the pre-calculated value(s) of `area(geo)` without having to call the `area()` function for each row in the table.

Essentially, the query can look like this in pseudo-code:

```
SELECT id, geo, area_index_value, desc
FROM rivers     
WHERE area_index_value >5000;
```

The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#i1006674) explains this well.

Comment: What if the `area` Oracle Function took a second argument, `y`, that was not in the `rivers` table? Could a function index not, then, be created? Or, what if `y` came from another table, e.g. `mountains`?

Comment: If Y was a constant, then it could be specified in the index definition. It cannot be read from a different table.